# What is the best way to use map and sorted together in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I want to iterate all items in my `array` and then change all strings. Then I want to sort the array with the new strings.

More specifically I have an array ["1,8", "3,5", "2,5", "4"] and want to change commas to dot and sort like [1.8, 3.5, 2.5, 4]

How can I achieve this by using `map` and `sorted`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`flatMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2903427-flatmap) with `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)` to ignore the nil result while converting string to number and then sort the result array.

```
let array = ["1,8", "3,5", "2,5", "4"]
let sortedArray = array.flatMap({ Double($0.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")) }).sorted()
print(sortedArray) //[1.8, 2.5, 3.5, 4.0]
```

**Note:** If your Swift version is 4.1 or greater than use [`compactMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap) because `flatMap` is deprecated in Swift 4.1.

```
let sortedArray = array.compactMap({ Double($0.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")) }).sorted()
```

Comment: Using `map` is sufficient here

Comment: @CAAnimationDelegate I know `map` is sufficient but what if string is not valid number then you need to wrap the result so instead of that better to use `flatMap`.

Comment: Btw what is the differences between map and compactMap? @NiravD

Comment: @Brkr Welcome mate :), `map` will include nil where as `compactMap` ignore the nil object, check this blog for more details http://www.thomashanning.com/swift-map-and-flatmap/

Comment: really appreciated for your help

Comment: @Brkr Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = ["1,8", "3,5", "2,5", "4"]
var sortedArray = array.map{Double($0.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "."))!}.sorted(by: {$0 < $1})
print(sortedArray)
```